# java-jwt with public/private keys

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

[Auth0](https://github.com/auth0) provides two JWT libraries, one for Node: [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), and one for Java: [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt).

I created the private/public key pair, and used it successfully in Node with [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken):

```
var key = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
var pem = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');

var header = {...};
var payload = {...};

header.algorithm = "RS256";
var message = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, key, header);
var decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(message, pem, {algorithm: "RS256"});
```

But I found no way of doing the same in Java with [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt).

**Anyone has a working example of how to use private/public keys for JWT in Java?**

Comment: Hi Predrag, I have the same requirement where I have to create a signed token with private key using java and verify the token with public key in node JS .. I am struck with how to load the privatekey (private key.pem)  file and create the signed  token
with  RS256  algorithm..  it would be great if you share any samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular library doesn't support it. But you can check others for Java that do. See here: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 33):

I used the following code for JWT in Java. Try it.

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

public class JWTJavaWithPublicPrivateKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("generating keys");
        Map<String, Object> rsaKeys = null;

        try {
            rsaKeys = getRSAKeys();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) rsaKeys.get("public");
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) rsaKeys.get("private");

        System.out.println("generated keys");

        String token = generateToken(privateKey);
        System.out.println("Generated Token:\n" + token);

        verifyToken(token, publicKey);

    }

    public static String generateToken(PrivateKey privateKey) {
        String token = null;
        try {
            Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // put your information into claim
            claims.put("id", "xxx");
            claims.put("role", "user");
            claims.put("created", new Date());

            token = Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS512, privateKey).compact();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return token;
    }

    // verify and get claims using public key

    private static Claims verifyToken(String token, PublicKey publicKey) {
        Claims claims;
        try {
            claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(publicKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

            System.out.println(claims.get("id"));
            System.out.println(claims.get("role"));

        } catch (Exception e) {

            claims = null;
        }
        return claims;
    }

    // Get RSA keys. Uses key size of 2048.
    private static Map<String, Object> getRSAKeys() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        keys.put("private", privateKey);
        keys.put("public", publicKey);
        return keys;
    }
}
```

```
Maven Dependency
```

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how can we use existing key, (already generated keys, stored in files)?

Comment: ```byte[] b1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(spec);```

Comment: This helped me a lot while trying to get the private key read from the external file such as application.yml in my case.  Thanks @Manu

Answer (score 15):

Recent versions (since [3.0.0](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/releases/tag/3.0.0)) of the auth0 java-jwt library supports [RSA and ECDSA](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt#available-algorithms) for signing JWT tokens using a public/private key pair.

Example of signing a JWT using java-jwt (based on the [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/tree/master#pick-the-algorithm)).

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTCreationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Map;

class JwtPKSigningExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> keys = generateRSAKeys();

        String token = null;
        try {
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keys.get("private");
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privateKey);
            token = JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer("pk-signing-example")
                    .sign(algorithm);
        } catch (JWTCreationException x) {
            throw x;
        }

        try {
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keys.get("public");
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null);
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer("pk-signing-example")
                    .build();
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);

            System.out.println(jwt.getToken());
        } catch (JWTVerificationException x) {
            throw x;
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> generateRSAKeys() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        return Map.of("private", keyPair.getPrivate(), "public", keyPair.getPublic());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.java;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.jose4j.jwk.JsonWebKeySet;
import org.jose4j.jws.AlgorithmIdentifiers;
import org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature;
import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims;
import org.jose4j.jwt.MalformedClaimException;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.InvalidJwtException;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumer;
import org.jose4j.jwt.consumer.JwtConsumerBuilder;
import org.jose4j.keys.resolvers.JwksVerificationKeyResolver;
import org.jose4j.keys.resolvers.VerificationKeyResolver;
import org.jose4j.lang.JoseException;

public class JWTSigningAndVerification {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String jwt = generateJWT();
        validateJWTwithJWKS(jwt);
    }

    private static String generateJWT() throws FileNotFoundException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, JoseException {

        JwtClaims jwt_claims = new JwtClaims();

        jwt_claims.setSubject("sub");
        jwt_claims.setIssuer("https://domain");
        jwt_claims.setIssuedAtToNow();
        jwt_claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(1000000);
        jwt_claims.setGeneratedJwtId();
        jwt_claims.setClaim("sid", "sessionid");
        jwt_claims.setClaim("email", "test@mail.com");
        jwt_claims.setClaim("given_name", "first");
        jwt_claims.setClaim("family_name", "last");

        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
        jws.setPayload(jwt_claims.toJson());
        String KeyPassword = "p12-key-password";
        File file = new File("path-to-key.p12");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        store.load(stream, KeyPassword.toCharArray());
        Enumeration e = store.aliases();
        String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
        PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) store.getKey(alias, KeyPassword.toCharArray());
        jws.setKey(key);
        jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue("1");
        jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_PSS_USING_SHA512);
        jws.setHeader("typ", "JWT");

        String jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();
        System.out.println(jwt);

        return jwt;
    }

    private static void validateJWTwithJWKS(String jwt) throws JoseException, FileNotFoundException, IOException,
            ParseException, InvalidJwtException, MalformedClaimException {

        JsonWebKeySet jsonWebKeySet = new JsonWebKeySet("json-jwks-escaped");
        VerificationKeyResolver verificationKeyResolver = new JwksVerificationKeyResolver(jsonWebKeySet.getJsonWebKeys());

        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder().setVerificationKeyResolver(verificationKeyResolver).build();

        JwtClaims claims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt);
        System.out.println("sub:- " + claims.getSubject());
    }

}
```

Comment: This code block can be used to sign a JWT and verify it using JWKS using jose4j library, let me know if you face any issues using it.