# JWT: jwtk/jjwt with public/private keys

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

[Auth0](https://github.com/auth0) provides two JWT libraries, one for Node: [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken), and one for Java: [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt). It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37730357/271873) that [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) does not support public/private key pairs.

However, another java library, the [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) library, claims to support that feature. However, the documentation does not show how one can use own public/private key pairs in [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt).

I created the private/public key pair, and used it successfully in Node with [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken):

```
var key = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
var pem = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');

var header = {...};
var payload = {...};

header.algorithm = "RS256";
var message = jsonwebtoken.sign(payload, key, header);
var decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(message, pem, {algorithm: "RS256"});
```

But I found no way of doing the same in Java with [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt).

**Anyone has a working example of how to use private/public keys for JWT in Java with [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)?**

Comment: FWIW: I'd advise you to use jose4j, https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home, the leading Java implementation of JOSE/JWT

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have followed

Create Keystore

> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks
>   -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048

You can create Key store from existing private key and public key. Google it how to do it.

Load Keystore

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream readStream = // Use file stream to load from file system or class.getResourceAsStream to load from classpath
    ks.load(readStream, "password".toCharArray());
    Key key = ks.getKey("selfsigned", "password".toCharArray());
    readStream.close();
```

Use JJwt api to sign the message

```
String s = Jwts.builder().setSubject("Abc").signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS512, key).compact();
```

Use JJwt api to claim the message

```
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(certificate.getPublicKey()).parseClaimsJws(s).getBody().getSubject().equals("Abc");
```

Comment: Can you please clarify where does keyEntry come from?

Comment: `PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getKey("selfsigned", "password".toCharArray());`

Comment: incompatible types: Key cannot be converted to PrivateKeyEntry - I guess getKey returns a Key that cannot be converted to a PrivateKeyEntry... :(